# Web-api :-The requested resource does not support HTTP method 'POST' - Angular5

Tags: asp.net-web-api, angular-cli

I can GET and POST from my Login apiController (so I can login/signup etc) but I can only GET from an API Controller in an area I have created. I get a 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Answer (score 0):

Check the file you are posting to. Certain web servers, nginx, for example, returns a 405 if you POST to a static file. It's possible that IIS won't accept POST if there is no data payload.

See if your parameters are actually in the data/post part of the request. If your login parameters are in the URL query string, it's still a GET even though your method claims to be a POST. The server might reject empty POST requests.